# How do I configure Ruby on Rails to Always use mySQL as the default database?

Tags: programming, mysql, ruby, rails

How do i configure Ruby on Rails to always use mySQL as the default database?

I am a newbie and i just installed Ruby on Rails and mySQL and by default **ROR** uses sqlite3, but when I configure the db file to use mysql instead of sqlite3, it gives all sorts of errors.

I tried installing the ruby mySQL gem, but still more errors. Should I just do another clean installation of Ubuntu? I'm currently using ver 10.10.

Answer (score 3):

you can use -d command line option when creating your app to use mysql instead of sqlite i.e

> rails -d mysql myapp